# Count the number of rows prior to the most recent instance of a row matching a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, row

Given the following dataframe:

| id_ | col |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 0 |
| 7 | 0 |

I'm looking to create a column that counts the number of rows since the most recent instance of `col == 1`. The final dataframe should look like:

| id_ | col | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |  |
| 2 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 3 |
| 6 | 0 | 1 |
| 7 | 0 | 2 |

I can build a simple looping function but I'm sure there's a clever vectorised way to do this. Any ideas would be most welcome!

Here's the code to create the dataframe:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

DataFrame(
    {
        'id_': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7},
        'col': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 0},
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
# Mask out the zero values, leaving 1 in place
# then count number of 1's using cumsum, this gives number of time value being 1
# shift the result, so we count row after value is changed

df['count']=df['col'].mask(df['col'].eq(0)).cumsum().ffill().shift(1)


# count value within each of the groups formed above
# this return the expected result

df['count']=df[df['count'].notna()].groupby('count')['count'].transform('cumcount')+1
df
```

```
    id_     col     count
0     1       0     NaN
1     2       1     NaN
2     3       0     1.0
3     4       0     2.0
4     5        1    3.0
5     6       0     1.0
6     7       0     2.0
```